# Is the GPS signal being scrambled near military bases

Tags: gps, navigation

We are navigating our survey aircraft using standard GPS receiver. Sometimes we fly near the vicinity of US Ramstein military base in Germany and it seems we are losing lock (no solution) in that area when making fast loops or turns. It only happens in this area. Is it possible they are somehow scrambling the signal? I haven't found this documented anywhere...

Comment: Why not use Google maps on a GNSS enabled smartphone and test your theory?  Drive near the base and see if your location is displaced as you get closer?  Since this is such a simple test I would think a conspiracy to hide jamming or spoofing without disclosing the fact to the public would be a moot point .  Is your fast turn hiding the GNSS antenna from a clear view of the sky?

Comment: We dont operate on the ground there. Its a 1000km drive away and kind of away from our common commutes. Antena is mounted below the helicopter rotor, but above all windshields - so on the outside.

Comment: The problem happened only twice, and always in this area, with 2 different antennas

Answer (score 1):

[Jamming](https://searchsecurity.techtarget.com/definition/GPS-jamming) or [spoofing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spoofing_attack) the GPS- (and most likely also other GNSS) signals near military bases would seem very logical to me and is very much possible from a technical standpoint. Also, officially documenting such security measures would be highly counterproductive.

Although losing the lock only when making fast loops seems somehow odd, maybe you lose control of the aircraft completely when you get closer to the base.

Answer (score 1):

How is your GNNS antennae mounted? My experience from doing airborne surveys is that I have lost the fix quite often during turns, as the hull of the airframe attenuates the signals differently.